# Windows 10 system restore storage drive swap

Tags: windows-10, storage, system-restore

So at a quick glance I do not see a way to do this,

I have system restore on, and want to keep it on.

It caches approximately 8.15 Gb, which is fine, but I want it to store the cache on the archive drive, which has more free space, than the solid state drive.

Is there a way to have system restore for drive C:, but have it store the needed restore files on drive D:?

Comment: try this: **Vssadmin resize ShadowStorage /For=C: /On=D: /MaxSize=20%** and look if it works to have the restore points on D: for Drive C:

Comment: @magicandre1981
Where would I look to verify that it is saved on D: and to verify no file on C: 

Also how would I verify that the content on D: is indeed restore point of C:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Vssadmin list shadows**](https://commandwindows.com/vssadmin.htm) shows I have two shadow copies, as well as some additional information.

I checked at a better [source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754968(v=ws.11).aspx) and it looks like I'll just add a new one and delete the old two, unless there is some way to move the original two I think this is the most cautious approach.

I wish there was a copy or move command that could be leveraged.