# Change the drive for system restore points?

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-restore

I want to move my C: System Restore Points to my archive HDD D: (which is 8TB big). Any way I can do that? I don't want these system restore points on my 250gb SSD.

Comment: What does your [research](https://www.bing.com/search?q=change+restore+point+location&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) indicate?  [Create System Restore Point, Restore computer using System Restore in Windows 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-system-restore-point)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1135153/windows-10-system-restore-storage-drive-swap?rq=1)

Comment: I don't think you can change the location per drive and it just uses the default location on each drive you enable this for.... however you can better control how large you let it grow using an admin elevated command prompt such as: `VSSADMIN RESIZE SHADOWSTORAGE /FOR=C: /ON=C: /MAXSIZE=1GB` ...... https://ss64.com/nt/vssadmin.html

Comment: System Restore points make a horrible backup system, they are great when you have to revert back to a previous configuration, but as an actual backup mechanic they are pretty bad.